# Python float operations

Tags: python, printing, floating-point, rounding

How can I print the full float result of a simple operation in python? My code does:

```
if( int(array_Y[counter2]) == int(round(float(elem[0])))):
                if(int(round(float(elem[0]))) == 0):
                    negatiu_verdader += 1
                if(int(round(float(elem[0]))) == 1):
                    positiu_verdader += 1
                counter = counter + 1
            counter2 = counter2 + 1

        error =  float(1.0000- (1.0000 * counter / counter2))

        print "        ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :" + ("{0:.15f}".format(round(error,2)))
```

But the error is always: `0.420000000000000` or `0.230000000000000` but I would like the error to be: `0.43233213213232`.

Comment: Python `if` statements do not need parenthesis; they make your code harder to read here.

Comment: If you are going to round and floor `elem[0]`, just do it *once*, not 3 times for all your if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rounding your error down to two decimal places by calling `round(error, 2)`:

```
>>> round(0.43233213213232, 2)
0.43
```

Don't do that if you want to show more precision:

```
>>> format(round(0.43233213213232, 2), '.15f')
'0.430000000000000'
>>> format(0.43233213213232, '.15f')
'0.432332132132320'
```

You do a lot of redundant work in your code, simplify it down a little:

```
elem_rounded = int(round(float(elem[0])))
if int(array_Y[counter2]) == elem_rounded:
    if not elem_rounded:
        negatiu_verdader += 1
    elif elem_rounded == 1:
        positiu_verdader += 1
        counter += 1
        counter2 += 1

    error =  1.0 - (1.0 * counter / counter2)
    print "        ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :{0:.15f}".format(error)
```